# What tools are there to create and manage an apt repository?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository

I'm currently in charge of packaging for Ubuntu some software my company creates and creating an apt repository for it. However, I'm having trouble finding tools to create and manage the repository with. I know about Ubuntu PPAs, but we want to have the packages in our own repository. I'd like to know what tools are there, so I can decide what is the best for the job.

Right now, I have only found **reprepro** on some debian howtos.. Is there any other tools out there for this job?

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: Off topic: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

reprepro is a good tool, but it's likely overkill for what you're doing.  I'd recommend looking at the apt-utils package.  It contains the tool apt-ftparchive which is perfect for maintaining a reasonably sized internal repository.

See [here](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository) for all the options and links to good howtos.

Answer (score 5):

under documentroot on your webserver

`mkdir myrepo`

copy all the .deb files to the myrepo folder

`cd myrepo`

`dpkg-scanpackages ./ /dev/null | gzip > Packages.gz`

Using the repository:

Add to /etc/apt/sources.list

`deb http://webserver/myrepo/ ./`

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising (and free too).  aptly http://www.aptly.info/

Answer (score 0):

[Nexus Repository](https://sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository) from sonatype.com is also able to host and manage apt reposiories. There is a free open-source version available, too. This comes with a web UI for managing the repository.